# performSegueWithIdentifier not working when being called from new instance of viewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, push-notification

### **My mission**

When app receive notification and user taps on the notification i want to redirect the user to the correct View. In my case, *SingleApplicationViewController*.

### **Current code**

***PushNotification.swift*** - A class with static functions to handle behaviors when receiving Push Notifications

The *__getNavigationController* returns a specific NavigationController based on a tab -and viewIndex from TabBarController.

```
internal static func __getNavigationController(tabIndex: Int, viewIndex: Int) -> UINavigationController {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let window:UIWindow? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window)!
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainEntry")
        window?.rootViewController = viewController

        let rootViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        rootViewController.selectedIndex = tabIndex
        let nav = rootViewController.viewControllers![viewIndex] as! UINavigationController

        return nav
    }
```

The *applicationClicked* is being called when user click on notification and that method calls on __getApplication to fetch the application from the db with the objectId received in the push notification and then instantiate a GroupTableViewController to perform segue to the SingleApplicationViewController.

```
(TabbarController -> Navigation Controller -> GroupTableViewController -> SingleApplicationViewController)
```

What is a bit strange is when I set **tabIndex to 0** and **viewIndex to 1**. The GroupView however is on second tab (tab 1) and the view controller should be the first (0). But when I set them to the corresponding numbers, I receive nil and the application crashes.

I read that you will force the view controller to load when doing `_ = groupTableViewController.view` and which it actually does. When this is being called, the viewDidLoad -function is being called.

```
/************** APPLICATION ***************/
    static func applicationClicked(objectId: String) {
        __getApplication(objectId) { (application, error) in
            if application != nil && error == nil {
                let nav = __getNavigationController(0, viewIndex: 1)
                let groupTableViewController = nav.viewControllers.first as! GroupsTableViewController
                _ = groupTableViewController.view

                groupTableViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GroupTableToApplicationToDetailApplication", sender: application!)
            } else {
                // Hanlde error
            }
        }
    }
```

***GroupTableViewController.prepareForSegue()***

Here I create a new instance of the ApplicationTableViewController, which is a middle step before getting to *SingleApplicationViewController*

```
} else if segue.identifier == "GroupTableToApplicationToDetailApplication" {
                let navC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
                let controller = navC.topViewController as! ApplicationViewController
                controller.performSegueWithIdentifier("ApplicationsToSingleApplicationSegue", sender: sender as! Application)
            }
```

### So, what's not working?

Well, the prepareForSegue in GroupTableViewController is not being called. I use **the same code structure on my TimeLineViewController**, and almost the exact same code, when getting another Push Notification and it works perfectly. In that case I use tabIndex 0 and viewIndex 0 to get the proper NavigationController.

Please, any thoughts and/or suggestions is more than welcome!

Comment: Your structure is not clear, if you want some help you could draw the structure or post a picture about your storyboard, like this it's very hard to understand what you call in a specific moment..

Comment: There's a lot of code in your question and I'm not convinced it's all necessary.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: I believe that it is all is necessary, though. I'm not sure of where the real problem lies, therefore I have to include all the code that has something to do with performing this segue. Although, I agree with @AlessandroOrnano, it maybe unclear of what's happening where. I'll try out the solution first and come back later with a pic. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is change in following method..

```
internal static func __getNavigationController(tabIndex: Int) -> UINavigationController {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let window:UIWindow? = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window)!
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainEntry")
        window?.rootViewController = viewController

        let rootViewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        rootViewController.selectedIndex = tabIndex
        let nav = rootViewController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController  //This will return navigation controller..
                        //No need of viewIndex..

        return nav
    }
```

you have written

```
let nav = rootViewController.viewControllers![viewIndex] as! UINavigationController
```

change to `rootViewController.selectedViewController` give you `UINavigationController`.

Here you get navigavtion controller object..In your applicationClicked method nav object might be nil so it can not execute further performsegue code.

Check following method.

```
/************** APPLICATION ***************/
    static func applicationClicked(objectId: String) {
        __getApplication(objectId) { (application, error) in
            if application != nil && error == nil {
                let nav = __getNavigationController(0)//0 is your tab index..if you want 1 then replace it with  1
                let groupTableViewController = nav.viewControllers.first as! GroupsTableViewController  //Rootview controller of Nav Controller
               groupTableViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GroupTableToApplicationToDetailApplication", sender: application!) //Perform seque from Root VC...
            } else {
                // Hanlde error
            }
        }
    }
```